# Can someone please tell me what i have wrong here

Tags: solidity, contract-development, test, safemath

```
function calculateSplitPercent() public {
    for(uint256 i = 0; i >= uniqueIdCounter; i++) {
        uint256 spliPercent = balanceOf[uniqueIdToAddress[i]].div(totalFunded).mul(100);
        addrsToSplitPercentage[uniqueIdToAddress[i]] = spliPercent;
        splitPercentageToAddrs[spliPercent] = uniqueIdToAddress[i];
    }
}
```

if you need the full code let me know.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please either share the full code or a minimal working example of the code. And please explain what you were trying to do and what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `spliPercent` to

```
uint256 spliPercent = balanceOf[uniqueIdToAddress[i]].mul(100).div(totalFunded);
```